# Get the path to the current application settings file

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I have so many bloody different nested folders with different names that were all automatically created by the settings engine that I can no longer tell where the active settings file resides on my machine. Is there a way to determine the path to the active settings file programmatically so I can output it to a debug console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't often that I can post the exact same answer within 2 minutes.  Copy-and-paste:

I'm going to be a bit blunt about this. The .NET framework design is overall rather excellent. Easy to learn, few surprises, no fat. But not everything is great. System.Configuration has a very high suck factor. Between an absurdly complicated object model and an implementation that was paralyzed by security concerns, it inevitably becomes a PITA when you try to extend it beyond the point-and-click settings designer.

Just don't go there. Using XML serialization to load/save your own configuration class(es) is a wholeheckofalot easier than battling that borked design.

Comment: I do often fantasize about ditching it and going with my own design. :)

Comment: What do you need?  Kick in the butt?  `(_*_)`

Comment: Lol. What I need is for everything else to be working perfectly, and then I will. :D

Comment: Ouch, shark infested waters `____/\\___\o/___`